# How to debug the This C code

Tags: c

While reading some question on a site I came across below question where a c question needs to be debug

```
unsigned int a, b, c;
/* a and b are assume to have some values */
c = (a + b) / 2; // <- There is a bug in this st
What is the bug? and how you debug it?
```

Some of the answer saying it could cause overflow(c=(a+b)/2).but really didn't get how it cause overflow?

Comment: can u please give a link to the site ?

Comment: http://geeksforgeeks.org/forum/topic/how-to-debug-the-c-code#post-36549

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `a` and/or `b` are very large then `a + b` could exceed the maximum size of an unsigned integer (see `MAX_UINT` in the [`limits.h`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/climits/) file). This would cause an overflow and so the result would be wrong. For example if `a` and `b` are both equal to 0x80000000 the result would be 0 in 32-bit arithmetic, rather than expected result 0x80000000.

To solve it you could use something like this instead:

```
c = a/2 + b/2 + (a % 2 == 1 && b % 2 == 1);
```

If you know that `b` is greater than `a` then you could use this slightly simpler version:

```
c = a + (b - a) / 2;
```

Read this article for information about how this bug appeared in binary search algorithms in may popular languages (though it talks about `signed int` rather than `unsigned int`):

- [Extra, Extra - Read All About It: Nearly All Binary Searches and Mergesorts are Broken](http://googleresearch.blogspot.com/2006/06/extra-extra-read-all-about-it-nearly.html)

Comment: @larsmans: Yes, the article is mostly (but not entirely, if you read carefully) about Java's `signed int`. But the reason I included the link was not so much because it directly answers the question (the article doesn't do that), but more because I thought it provides useful background as to *why* this question is interesting / relevant and *why* knowing the answer can be important.

Answer (score 8):

`a+b` may overflow if the sum of `a` and `b` is larger than `UINT_MAX`, the maximum value for an `unsigned int`. E.g.,

```
unsigned a = 1;
unsigned b = UINT_MAX;

printf("%u\n", (a+b)/2);
```

prints `0`.

If you want to find the average of two `unsigned int`s without overflow, do

```
c = a/2 + b/2 + (a % 2 & b % 2);
```

(or `(a%2 + b%2)/2`, or `(a%2 && b%2)`, or `((a&1) & (b&1))`, etc.)

Comment: this answer made me to bump up question too.

Answer (score 2):

As other say:

```
unsigned int a, b, c;
c = (a + b) / 2;
```

`a + b` can be not representable in an `unsigned int` for some value of `a` and `b`.

A very similar situation led to a famous bug in the standard Java binary search implementation (`binarySearch` function).

See this famous Joshua Blosh blog post in 2006:

*"Extra, Extra - Read All About It: Nearly All Binary Searches and Mergesorts are Broken"*
http://googleresearch.blogspot.com/2006/06/extra-extra-read-all-about-it-nearly.html

Excerpts:

> The bug is in this line:
>
> 6:             int mid =(low + high) / 2;

further down:

> So what's the best way to fix the bug? Here's one way:
>
> 6:             int mid = low + ((high - low) / 2);

Note that in Joshua post, `high` is `>= low` and also  `int` objects were used but Java treats signed overflow as wrapping. In C signed integer overflows are undefined behavior and unsigned wraparound.

Comment: @Amit: I posted the same information in my answer, except that I posted an hour before this. I also linked to the exact same article as this post does. And I also included the solution of the highest voted answer (and also before he posted it). Now don't get me wrong, I'm not upset, I'm just slightly curious... why didn't I also get an upvote from you? Was my answer hard to understand? Did you somehow not see it? Please tell me what I did wrong so that I can improve my answers in future.

Comment: Hey @Mark I already up vote for you and really appreciate for your help.

Comment: @MarkByers from the edit timeline of your answer, you didn't add your link 1 hour before my post as you edited your answer 1 hour after your original answer to add the link.  It is possible that we both put the same information in our answers but for sure, I didn't take it from you.

Comment: @ouah: You can see from the edit history of my post that I added the link in version 2 which has timestamp "2012-02-23 09:59:19Z" (if you don't have enough reputation to see the edit history, you can ask another user to verify this for you). The first version of your post was at "2012-02-23 10:50:30Z", which is about one hour later. Again, I'm not bitter... I'm just wondering was my post hard to understand or unclear in some way? If so, I'd like to know what's wrong so that I can improve it. This will both help other people reading this page, and also help me become a better writer.

Comment: @MarkByers I cannot see the timestamps, but the now "rounded timestamp" hour of the answer just turned, it shows you were the first with this information. I'm not so surprised by the difference of upvotes between answers as I am often in complete disagreement with what answer SO users chose to be the best answer. +1 for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

It could cause overflow if `a` and `b` are high enough to yield an `a + b` higher than the maximum representable by an `unsigned int`.

Answer (score 0):

If you only declare a variable in C without initialize it, it gets *an unpredictably value*. a and b can be some value which is currently at the adress they get in the memory.

You can debug C code in Eclipse CDT 
http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/

With this IDE you can program in C anc C++ and it contains the GDB debugger. 
http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/